# How to stop restarting list in selectize input after click in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

When I filter a list of states in Shiny for: "New" I can choose only one state. After that the list is restarting and I have to put: "New" again in order to find a state contains "New" in name. I would like to filter states and choose more states at one time.

Below I added a picture and a code which present my goal.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQIJP.png)

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(


      selectizeInput(
        'e2', '2. Multi-select', choices = state.name, multiple = TRUE
      )

    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput('ex_out')

    )
  )
)



server <- function(input, output) {
  output$ex_out <- renderPrint({
    sapply(sprintf('e%d', 2), function(id) {
      input[[id]]
    })

  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I  dont think we can do this easily in R Shiny.

Comment: I misunderstood the question and gave the wrong answer. The solution you are expecting requires some javascript work I guess. It is not easy to do it in shiny.